# Achieve IntelliJ Idea to build and re-run a Spark Java project on file edit/update

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spark-java, file-watcher

I'd like to automate a process. I'm using [Spark Java](http://sparkjava.com/) framework and after build and run the first time, I'd like [IntelliJ Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) to watch file changes, stop, build and run the Spark Java application with the latest edits.

I know that there is the [File-Watchers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-watchers.html) plugin, although I'm not able to configure it correctly.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kindly suggested in this [thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000396959-Achieve-IntelliJ-Idea-to-build-and-re-run-a-Spark-Java-project-on-file-edit-update?page=1#community_comment_360000086359) by Serge Baranov, it seems that a special InteeliJ Idea run configuration would be needed to support this kind of feature.

I made a feature request over at JetBrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196700

Stay tuned